# Asp.net Core 3.1 'Authentication' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http' error when trying to access login.cshtml on live site

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, asp.net-core-3.1

I have a large app which I've just upgraded from .net Core 2.2 to 3.1

It works fine offline, including the login page (which is a version of Microsoft's template login page with minor alterations)

Online, however, I get this error when trying to access login.cshtml

> ...Views\Account\Login.cshtml(3,33): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Authentication' does not exist in the
> namespace 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http' (are you missing an assembly reference?)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation.RuntimeViewCompiler.CompileAndEmit(RazorCodeDocument
> codeDocument, String generatedCode)

I've tried searching the app for instances where Authentication might refer to AspNetCore.Http but there don't seem to be any, and anyway, it works offline.

It's not my server, so I can't check settings - but what setting might it be?

Comment: Did you update the dotnet runtime on the server?

Comment: it's not my server, but it runs 3.1 - hence I had to update my app. another site I updated similarly works fine.